# Flutter & Getx : bottomNavigationBar - Controller initialization

Tags: flutter, binding, controller, flutter-getx

Actually, I'm building a basic **social media app**. Users need to create an account and log in to use this app.

One of its features ensures a quick connection. If a user is already logged in, closes the app, and reopens it, they'll be taken straight to the home screen, bypassing the login screen.

For this matter, I've created two screens: a splash screen (with a FastConnectionController to validate user tokens) and a navbar screen (with an AppController to retrieve user information and HomeController to manage the navbar screen's state). Additionally, I've created a home screen (without a controller), a settings screen (also without a controller), and an events screen (managed by EventsController).
The user can easily navigate to the Home, Events, and Settings screens from the navbar.

I've established the following bindings for the application:

- [main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K55mO.png)
- [initial binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KskRj.png)
- [splash screen binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFINy.png)
- [home binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0znQA.png)
- [event binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F25b4.png)
- [navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPcOI.png)

The issue is that when I open the app, the EventsController is being initialized even before reaching the events screen. Could someone explain this to me and perhaps suggest a solution to initialize this controller only when I open the events screen and delete it when I leave that page?

- [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKoFG.png)

Many thanks in advance.

I make the event screen extend from GetView EventController, and the problem remains unchanged. But it returns that error. Why?